# Mocking library for Vala

Tags: mocking, vala

I would like to write unit tests using mock object, like [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) or [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.com/) for C#. 
Could anyone recommend a mocking library  for use with Vala?

Answer (score 1):

Because Vala generates C-Code (using GObject lib), you can use C-mocking libraries like [test-dept](https://code.google.com/p/test-dept/).